# Ways to register custom interceptors in some spring boot projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a `nmj-api-framework` project which is a spring boot backend web project.
In the project, I've defined some `interceptors` extended `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and registered them by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.
I think it's the common way to use interceptors.
[Using Spring MVC HandlerInterceptor with Spring Boot - Hello World example](http://www.javainuse.com/spring/bootInterceptor) showed the details.

Then I have some other projects which depends on `nmj-api-framework`, e.g. `nmj-api-project1` and `nmj-api-project2`.
I'd like to **register other custom interceptors in these projects** and not modify the base project `nmj-api-framework`.
Are there some ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is dependent on how the Spring Context between your `nmj-api-framework`, `nmj-api-project1` and `nmj-api-project2` is shared.

If there is single component scan, you can just register interceptor in `nmj-api-project1` and `nmj-api-project2` (as described in blog post you pointed out) and component scanning should find and use it.

Comment: Can I specify the order of interceptors which are registered in different `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` classes? I found the interceptor registered in `nmj-api-project1` ran before that registered in `nmj-api-framework`.

Comment: You can use `@Order` annotation to explicitly specify order in which are your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` beans registered.

Comment: Or if you can't change `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` in your nmj-api-framework projct, just use `@DependsOn`